# Not able to connect local postgres instance from Airflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, airflow

I am trying to connect to a source DB from Airflow so that I can design data pipeline from source to destination. But whenever I try to establish a new postgres connection from Airflow it is throwing error.

The postgres instance is installed in my local and running on 5434 port.

I am running Airflow from Docker.

My postgressql.conf

[image]

My pg_hba.conf

[image]

Airflow connnection window

[image]

With port 5432:

[image]

Port and config details :

[image]

Comment: Your default port is 5432 not 5434

Comment: I've tried with 5432 first. Airflow threw error, so tried with port 5434. With port 5434 my postgres is running fine. I can access the schema from terminal. BUt from Airflow it is not connecting.

Comment: Then connect to PostgreSQL and run `SHOW port;`, `SHOW listen_addresses;` and `TABLE pg_hba_file_rules;` and see if the result is what you expect. Then change the port in your Airflow dialog back to 5432 and add the error message that you get to your question.

Comment: Updated the details in my question.